# How to mount the volume of host to docker container with executable file permission using docker api

Tags: docker, file-permissions

When I tried to create django docker container using remote api, I can bind the host volume to docker container volume. But when I use "Cmd" along with docker create, it showing an error(not for shell commands),

```
<Response [500]>
Cannot start container d07b316a1d790b67442a9a4ee49de6e6f2191e14d15ebd528d752b3fad63d9b1: exec: "pip install -r requirements.txt&& python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8888": executable file not found in $PATH
```

This is my json input.

```
d = {
     "Hostname": "",
     "Domainname": "",
     "User": "",
     "Memory": 0,
     "MemorySwap": 0,
     "CpuShares": 512,
     "Cpuset": "0,1",
     "AttachStdin": True,
     "AttachStdout": True,
     "AttachStderr": True,
     "Tty": True,
     "OpenStdin": True,
     "StdinOnce": False,
     "Env": "[$PATH=/usr/local/bin]",
     "Cmd": [
             "pip install -r requirements.txt&& python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8888"
     ],
     "Entrypoint": "",
     "Image": "django:python3",
     "Volumes": {
             "/usr/src/app": {},
     },
     "WorkingDir": "/usr/src/app",
     "NetworkDisabled": False,
     "MacAddress": mac_id,
     "ExposedPorts": {
             "8888/tcp": {}
     },
     "SecurityOpts": [""],
     "HostConfig": {
       "Binds": ["/home/user/Sample:usr/src/app"],
       "Links": [],
       "LxcConf": {"lxc.utsname":"docker"},
       "PortBindings": { "8888/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "8888" }] },
       "PublishAllPorts": False,
       "Privileged": False,
       "ReadonlyRootfs": False,
       "Dns": ["8.8.8.8"],
       "DnsSearch": [""],
       "ExtraHosts": '',
       "VolumesFrom": [],
       "CapAdd": ["NET_ADMIN"],
       "CapDrop": ["MKNOD"],
       "RestartPolicy": { "Name": "", "MaximumRetryCount": 0 },
       "NetworkMode": "bridge",
       "Devices": []
    }
}
```

Using "docker run" command it works fine for me. How can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the remote API, but the problem is that you've passed it all as a single argument, so it's looking for a file called `"pip install -r requirements.txt&& python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8888"`.

You need to figure out how to pass the arguments separately, and you may need to give an absolute path to pip.

Comment: Sorry? That's the problem; you need to figure out how to split it up.

Comment: Its showing the same error even if the command is **pip install <something>** or **python manage.py <something>** ie any command other than shell script

Comment: Look up the docs. I'm pretty sure you are not passing the arguments correctly. For example `/bin/ls` will work as there is an executable at that path. `/bin/ls -a` probably won't work as it looks like the whole string including the ` -a` is being interpreted as a file path.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have `pip` installed inside your container? For instance, on Debian-derivative system your Dockerfile should have this:

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get -y install python-pip
```

Comment: pip is already installed. Im trying out with docker api **create container**

Comment: @pheonix, for debug purposes (since you need to check what's happen to `pip` or `python`) try to put your CMD instructions in a simple bash script, load it into the container and mark them as an ENTRYPOINT of your container. You can p